# where/when can i buy a native ubuntu superphone?

Tags: smartphone

i'm not a techie, so I don't want to convert another phone.

I want to buy an "off-the-shelf", ready-to-go, fully supported ubuntu superphone.

where/when can i buy a native ubuntu superphone?

Answer (score 2):

The [Ubuntu Phone FAQ](http://insights.ubuntu.com/news/get-the-faqs-about-ubuntu-on-smartphones/) mentions the following:

> ## When will it be available to buy?
>
> This depends mainly on our partners’ roadmaps, but we are working with these partners today and expect the Ubuntu to be available on phones during 4th quarter 2013 or in early 2014.

You can [register here](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/register) to be notified once they are available.

Answer (score 0):

If Mark Shuttleworth is to be believed, you can [order one right now for $830 on the crowd-funding site indiegogo](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge). They are described as a 'superphone'. The estimated delivery date is May 2014.